# Burp extender ---- How to write a extender of intruder?

Tags: burp

Recently, I need to write a custom payload generator in burp's intruder module
[image]

Then I googled it and do as the articles from internet, but there are two interface, I don't know what to do.

[image]

Should I implement them both or what ?? Can anyone give me an answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement both to get a working generator. There is an example [here](https://github.com/PortSwigger/example-intruder-payloads). The key parts are:

```
class IntruderPayloadGenerator implements IIntruderPayloadGenerator
{
    ...
}

class IntruderPayloadGeneratorFactory implements IIntruderPayloadGeneratorFactory
{
    @Override
    public IIntruderPayloadGenerator createNewInstance(IIntruderAttack attack)
    {
        // return a new IIntruderPayloadGenerator to generate payloads for this attack
        return new IntruderPayloadGenerator();
    }
    ...
}

callbacks.registerIntruderPayloadGeneratorFactory(IntruderPayloadGeneratorFactory());
```